# why does using addDate in tmap doesnt return proper result

Tags: talend

`tmap` date filter not working:

Sorry am new to talend.. I want to filter my rows by `inventory_date` i want to match it with date-7 . I have written the below query:

```
row2.inventory_date==TalendDate.addDate("2/11/2018","m/dd/yyyy",-7,"dd")
```

Here am trying to match my inventory_date column to "2/4/2018". But its not filtering and instead giving 0 rows.

```
`row2.inventory_date==TalendDate.addDate("2/11/2018","m/dd/yyyy",-7,"dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the '==' to compare dates in tMap.  Try using Talend.compareDate:

TalendDate.compareDate(row2.inventory_date,TalendDate.addDate("2/11/2018","m/dd/yyyy",-7,"dd"),"m/dd/yyyy") == 0

There is additional documentation for the variuos forms of comparDate in the expression builder.